# How to prevent the repetition of object name for Python using autocompletion in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pylance

I am using VSCode for writing Python code in a Jupyter Notebook. The relevant extensions installed are [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) and [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter). The problem occurs when I try to use tab to autocomplete method names for any object. For example, if the suggestion box looks like this:

[image]

and I press Tab to accept the suggestion, the object name `database` is repeated i.e the code looks like `dataset.dataset.as_numpy_iterator` instead of `dataset.as_numpy_iterator`. How can I remove this object name duplication? Thanks!

Comment: If you see carefully, only ```as``` is highlighted. What happens if you click on it?

Comment: @Sujay The same thing. It repeats dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time searching for a fix, I tried using the latest Insider's build (instead of the stable build) of VSCode and surprise surprise - it did not have this issue. Moreover, even in the stable build, it occurs only in Jupyter Notebooks and not in standalone .py files. I am posting this as an answer so that other people don't have to waste more time on this!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like provided by some extension you have installed. Such as `Tabnine AI`, `Kite` and so on. But I can't reproduce it on both of them.

I can't get to know which extension provides it in your picture, it looks like was cut off in your picture. But it does not provide by the Python extension.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't have any autocomplete extension installed except for Pylance. However, I tried using the latest Insider's build (instead of the stable build) of VSCode and surprise surprise - it did not have this issue. Moreover, even in the stable build, it occurs only in Jupyter Notebooks and not in standalone .py files. I'll post this comment as a separate answer so that other people don't waste time on this!

Comment: @Mohit Garg Thanks for your reply, have a good day : ).

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same issue. Simply **disabling and re-enabling** the Jupyter Keymap extension solved my problem.

Judging from the lack of related search results, this issue seems to occur only under some rare circumstance...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).